# Python: While Loops, Executing the same code under different conditions. Elegance and overhead

Tags: python, while-loop

In python:
I am looking to execute the same block of code in a while loop, but under different conditions, with a flag for which condition should be checked. 
Also, the flags will not, in this case, change during execution, and only one flag will be active for this segment of the program.

I could do this as follows:

```
#user inputs flag
if flag == "flag1": flag1 = True
elif flag == "flag2": flag2 = True
#...
#define parameters    
while (flag1 and condition1) or (flag2 and condition2) ... or (flagN and conditionN):
    #do stuff #using parameters
```

This method is OK, seeing as it will only check the flags, and not calculate the conditions for each bracket every time, due to the way "and" works in python.

or

```
def dostuff(parameters):
    #do stuff

#user inputs flag
if flag == "flag1": flag1 = True
elif flag == "flag2": flag2 = True
#...

#define parameters

if flag1:
    while(condition1):
        dostuff(parameters)
elif flag2:
    while(condition2):
        dostuff(parameters)
etc... down to N
```

would accomplish the same thing, probably the same overhead.

I was just wondering if anyone can suggest a better method, in terms of programming practice and readability,or if this is the best general approach.

Thanks

Comment: Your examples aren't equivalent: If flag status changes in the first example, the loop may continue if the condition for the new flag matches. However, when first checking the flags as in your second example, this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Finwood, good point. The flags will not change during execution.

Comment: @MrJanx, your accepted answer and your own code are not doing the same thing. You may as well do `for cond in list_of_conditions:while cond...`, the flag is not being checked at all, worse again if the flags have duplicate values you will lost conditions as you will have duplicate keys

Comment: Ok, thanks... I've seen both your comments Padraic, but I haven't tried the code yet.
Let me double check.

Comment: Yup. I am happy with the lambda dictionary. The flag is only a marker for which condition must be checked, and as, in this set-up, exactly one condition must be checked, it's ok. My own code would work if multiple conditions needed to all be checked, which is why I was not completely happy with it in the first place - it seemed unnecessary.

Comment: @MrJanx, you still cannot have duplicate keys, what exactly are the potential values of each flag?

Comment: it would be something like:

Comment: it would be something like: {"flag1": lambda: e-score > a, "flag2": lambda:  z-score > b, "flag3": lambda: linecount < c, "flag4": lambda: average_z-score>d}, with the variables on the left-hand-side of the lambda calculation being calculated from data read in during the while loop. With flag, and a,b,c, or d being selected by user input.

Comment: I am a little confused as to where the flags fitted into your original code

Comment: Ok. I have been looking over it, and I see your confusion. In the original code, I would have set exactly one of the flags to True, to set which conditional to check. With the dictionary approach, I do not need to set the flag to true, I just need to know which flag is input.

Comment: Edited OP again for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `dict` of lambda expressions:

```
conditions = {
    flag1: lambda: cond1,
    flag2: lambda: cond2,
    flag3: lambda: cond3}

while conditions[flag]():
    do_stuff(parameters)
```

Example:

```
conditions = {
    "flag1": lambda: x < 10,
    "flag2": lambda: x < 3,
    "flag3": lambda: x < 5}

x = 0
while conditions["flag2"]():
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

output:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this one!

Comment: where does flag come from?

Comment: It's a variable or constant or whatever. That's how I understand "with a flag for which condition should be checked".

Comment: This only checks the condition not if the flag also evaluates to True

Comment: sure, but earlier on you can specify:
 
    flag = "flag1"

then later:
 
    while conditions[flag]:
        #do stuff

If i didn't explain properly in the question, exactly one flag will be true at any time

Answer (score 4):

You could use any:

```
while any((flag1 and condition1),(flag2 and condition2),(flagN and conditionN))
```

There is also a difference between your two methods, if any condition can affect another then the two examples can behave differently.

You could also make a container of pairings and iterate:

```
data = ((flag1, condition1),(flag2, condition2),(flagN,conditionN))

for flag, cond in data:
   if flag:
       while cond:
         do_stuff(parameters)
```

It will avoid repeating code and is readable.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post, to specify that the flags won't change during execution, and only one will be active at any time.

Comment: You can replace `if flag: while cond:` with `while flag and cond:`.

Comment: @Maxime,  that is not the same thing.

Comment: Why? OP stated that "the flags will not, in this case, change during execution".

Comment: @Maxime, exactly, so why repeatedly  check something that is not going to change? It is irrelevant anyway as the OP has changed the question requirements.

Comment: Haven't exactly changed the requirements, just clarified. Thank you both. Your solution works better if I need to check multiple conditions Padraic, which I may need to do in future. While only needing to check one, Maxines is great.